# Trying to understand "Deriving natural deduction rules from truth tables" and having trouble with false hypothetical judgments

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

[image]

For rows of the truth table where the connective is false the connective is placed as a judgement. This doesn't make sense to me. Having the false proposition be in the hypothetical position makes more sense, as implication can be cast that way.

Comment: You have to compare it with the formulation of ND with General Elimination Rules; see [Negri-von Plato](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Structural_Proof_Theory/ZvACGkn9138C), page 166-on.

Comment: Consider the case e.g. with $\land$ as connective: the GER is "if we have a derivation $\Gamma \vdash A_1 \land A_2$ and a derivation $\Gamma,A,B \vdash D$, we can conclude with $\Gamma \vdash D$". This rule fits with $\text {el}$ rule above when both $A_i$ are $0$. The two "mixed" cases can be reduced to it...

Comment: (Voted to reopen) Truth tables can actually be derived from natural deduction rules. The truth table for logical implication, for example, can be thought of as simply a convenient visualization of the theorem: $(A\land B \to (A\to B))\land (A\land \neg B\to \neg (A\to B))\land (\neg A\land B \to (A\to B))\land (\neg A \land \neg B \to (A\to B))$

Comment: Thanks for reopening and answering! @MauroALLEGRANZA what you are saying makes sense, but I can't understand the reasoning behind what the author is saying. If the truth table connective is false why does it matter what I do with the components. They say that the truth table role determines the component positions as Lemma or Casus. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Agreed... without further context regarding the textbook used, it is difficult to understand what the author is trying to do. Obviously, rules are *sound*, meaning that when the premises are TRUE, also the *conclusion* must be. This gives us an hint regarding the link between truth-table and rules, but for a connective (e.g. $\land$) we have two rules: one for I and one for E while the four rows of the t-t APPARENTLY will produce four rules...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA well the problem is that's about all the context provided in the paper: http://www.cs.ru.nl/~herman/PUBS/NatDedTruthTables_Extended.pdf. They do say the rules can be reduced to the common two.

Comment: IMO the authors adapted to ND the approach used in [Kalmar completeness proof](https://ceur-ws.org/Vol-677/10_LANMR10.pdf) for Hilbert-style propositional logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I actually got a reply from the author, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: The moderation here is very severe, I will post the reply once I finish fully validating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herman Geuvers, one of the authors, answered over email:

There is a more philosophical explanation in

- P. Milne,
  Inversion Principles and Introduction Rules. In Dag Prawitz on Proofs
  and Meaning, volume 7 of Outstanding Contributions to Logic, pages
  189–224. Springer, 2015,
  who devised the rules (from TT to ND and back) independently from us,
  for classical logic. It is based on Gentzen-Prawitz' "inversion
  principles" and there is much more literature on that referred to in
  Milne's paper and in our paper:
- Herman Geuvers and Tonny Hurkens,
  Proof Terms for Generalized Natural Deduction, In 23rd International
  Conference on Types for Proofs and Programs (TYPES 2017), editors A.
  Abel, F. Nordvall Forsberg and A. Kaposi, LIPIcs Vol 104, Schloss
  Dagstuhl--Leibniz-Zentrum fuer Informatik, 2018, pages 3:1--3:39.
  https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/10051/

a truth table `row ...|0` for a formula `Phi = c(A_1,..,A_n)` corresponds to something like

```
(1) A_i, ..., ~A_j, ... |- ~Phi
```

whereas the corresponding elimination rule corresponds to something like

```
(2) for all Psi, (Phi, A_i, ..., (A_j -> Psi), ... |- Psi)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(3) for all Psi, (A_i, ..., (A_j -> Psi), ... |- Phi -> Psi)
```

From a classical point of view, any Psi is either true or false, so equivalent to Top or Bot,
and (3) holds trivially for `Psi = Top`, so classically (3) is equivalent to the special case `Psi = Bot:`

```
(4) A_i, ..., (A_j -> Bot), ... |- Phi -> Bot
```

which is equivalent to (1).
But constructively, (1) only expresses the special case of applying the elimination rule to `Psi = Bot`.
For example, the well-known elimination rule for disjunction `Phi = A_1 \/ A_2`,
corresponding to the row 0,0|0 (in which the formula Phi is indeed false),
corresponds to the theorem:

```
(5) for all Psi, (A_1 -> Psi) -> (A_2 -> Psi) -> Phi -> Psi
```

and not to just

```
(6) ~A_1 -> ~A2 -> ~Phi.
```

For example, by applying (5) to `Psi = A_2 \/ A_1` we can derive `Phi |- A_2 \/ A_1`
which cannot be done constructively using just theorems like (6) that correspond to the rows of the truth table of connective `\/`.

Also note that there are many constructively definable connectives with the same truth table as `a_1 \/ A_2`
(like `~A_1 -> A_2 or ~(~A_1 /\ ~A_2)`)
for which our derivations rules derived from the truth table are NOT correct!